# linux bash redirection with stdin and stdout the same file

Tags: linux, bash, redirect

i have a problem about bash, command is like:

```
echo helloworld > hello.txt 
cat <hello.txt >hello.txt
```

at first, there are stuff in hello.txt.  what i expect is that it should seem nothing happens to hello.txt after executing the command, but there is nothing in hello.txt then.
is it a mechanism of bash, or is there something i did not understand about linux file descripor?
maybe bash establish only one fd for a certain file? am i right?
can you help me?

/br
ruan

Comment: Redirecting output empties the file immediately, before `cat` can read from it.

Comment: Won't work. out to a tmp file and then cat the tmp file to the original file. The redirect operator > will clear out the tmp file and write new content in.

Comment: Basically you are trying to use the same file for both input and output in a single command which wont work.So the moment you issue the  cat <hello.txt >hello.txt, hello.txt is opened for writing by clearing all its contents. And subsequently there is no text in hello.txt to get the input from.

Answer (score 0):

Use a temporary file

```
cat hello.txt > /var/tmp/tmpFile
mv -f /var/tmp/tmpFile hello.txt
cat hello.txt
```